# Match diacritics to latin alphabet equivalent

Tags: actionscript-3, string-matching, diacritics

How can I match lower case `i` and variants like `í` for example in ActionScript 3, please?

**EDIT:** The above is just an example, I am interested in matching all diacritics and special letters in general with a similar Latin Alphabet equivalent.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure if this answers your question, but: `String("help mí").replace(/í/g, "i") == "help mi"; // should return true`

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it, but the above was only an example. I need something to work with all diacritics. I am now using an array of diacritics and equivalent for each and doing something similar to what you wrote above, but I'm worried about performance. There are many strings, hundreds, that need to go through that at runtime for a real time ArrayCollection filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no relation (that I know of) behind the numeric character values of visually (and possibly audibly) similar characters. Hence, you will need to keep a lookup table between the regular 26 character alphabet and the diacritic versions of each character from that alphabet.

Comment: Grr, was hoping there was. Thank you.